# How do you edit source HTML with CKEditor 4.x contenteditable enabled?

Tags: ckeditor

Using CKEditor 4.x's inline editing feature (using the contenteditable attribute), how do you edit source HTML when you need to do something like paste in a YouTube embed snippet?

It seems like there should be a way to click on an edit source button and have the source appear in a dialog box or something. Overall, the inline editing is great, but sometimes I need to edit/paste HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source Dialog plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sourcedialog) is available since [CKEditor 4.1](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released) and maintained by the core team. I believe this is what you need:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'sourcedialog';
```

[More](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_sourcearea) about editing source in CKEditor.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for. Works great.